# Multiple controller method updating same entity. One method overwrites changes made by other controller method

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two APIs given below.

In real-life scenario, both api gets called simultaneously with same `id`. By the time `api_2` completes the "long calculation", `api_1` is already done and `entity` is updated.

Now, when `api_2` updates the entity, it discards the changes made by `api_1`.

Is there any way to tell hibernate to update only the specific columns I want to update?

api_1:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/api_1/{id}")
String api1(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    MyEntity entity = service.findByTxnId(id);
    entity.column1 = "API_1";
    service.save(entity);
    return "api_1";
}
```

api_2:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/api_2/{id}")
String api2(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    MyEntity entity = service.findByTxnId(id);

    // long calculation using `entity`

    entity.column2 = "API_2";
    service.save(entity);
    return "api_2";
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ssl_payments")
class SSLPayment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "col1")
    String column1;
    @Column(name = "col2")
    String column2;
}
```

Comment: Use a locking mechanism either pessimistic (database locks) or optimistic (version/timestamp).

Comment: @M.Deinum could you point me to any online articles about it?

Comment: The hibernate documentation (or JPA in general) explains this.